# In php is possible to access elements of the current Array by index?

Tags: php, arrays

In php is possible to access elements of the current  Array by index?
Example:

```php
$arr = array(
    'index1' => function() {
        echo 'foo'; //foo
    },
    'index2' => function() {
        $arr['index1']() // foo ??????????
        echo 'bar';  //bar
    }
);
```

how to call `$arr['index1']()` in `$arr` ?

Comment: i dont know what that is, but its not valid php

Comment: It's valid PHP except for the missing semicolon

Comment: The php is valid but you cannot reference the array from within the array.

Comment: forgive my Friday afternoon brain, it starts the weekend hours before  the rest of me does

Comment: @Dagon the rest of you - which is already almost a day before most of the rest of us. (Thur evening here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `$arr` is a variable defined outside the function, so it cannot be accessed from within the function.

It's tempting to try to just import the `$arr` variable into the [closure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) using `use ($arr)`, but that won't work because `$arr` isn't actually defined at the time you're defining your function.

As long as `$arr` is really a global varable, you can update the function like this to make it work:

```
'index2' => function() {
    global $arr;
    $arr['index1'](); // foo
    echo 'bar';  //bar
}
```

A better idea, though, is to pass the array in as a parameter to the function, like this:

```
'index2' => function($a) {
    $a['index1'](); // foo
    echo 'bar';  //bar
}
```

...and call it like this:

```
$arr['index2']($arr);
```

Comment: Note this syntax requires PHCrap 5.4

Comment: @jcsanyi Don't you still need 5.4 for that?

Comment: Are you thinking of [function array dereferencing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)?

Comment: @ColeJohnson This looks similar, but is actually different. It's the difference between `[]()` and `()[]`.